# Mapping and handling columns during mysqliport from SCV to DB

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am searching an functional example how to import data from CSV into MySQL table via **mysqlimport utility**. [(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html)

**The problem is following:**

- column names in table are differnt as in CSV
- during import, first charcter in particular column must be omited.

**Example:**
MySQL table name: **TABLE_A**

columns:

- id (int)
- name (varchar(50))
- salary (int)

CSV File: **file.csv**:

columns:

- id
- first name
- emp salary

**How looks data in CSV?**

1, John, $500

2, Mary Bell, $600

3, Adam Dave, $700

**Main problem is**

- mapping of columns
- omit '$' from 'SALARY' column

If you have any idea, I will be very grateful.

Comment: think your best and most easy option is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html.. it can import CVS data, skip the CVS header and use SQL statements to replace/remove data

Comment: ok, and how could you write this script. Could you use examples from my question?